# Pig output to MongoDb - renaming fields

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, apache-pig

I've been working on some code to generate data from pig and feed to MongoDb using the MongoDb-Hadoop Connector, which is working fine.

However, I've been trying to rename the field names or attributes you may call it, when they get stored in the MongoDb collection.

This is what I use to store results in the collection.

```
 results = FOREACH all avgone::code, avgone::year, avgone::month,
 STORE results INTO 'mongodb://hostname:27017/test.all' USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoInsertStorage('','');
```

This is stored as

```
"avgone::code":1,"avgone::year":2016.. and so on
```

I need it like this -

```
code:1,year:2016....
```

Is this possible?

I've tried:

```
 STORE results INTO 'mongodb://hostname:27017/test.all' USING com.mongodb.hadoop.pig.MongoInsertStorage('{code,year,month}','');
```

But I think it's the wrong way to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename the fields (change the schema) in your FOREACH using the AS keyword:

```
 results = FOREACH a GENERATE avgone::code AS code, avgone::year AS year, avgone::month AS month, ...
```